# this page is trying to load script from unauthenticated source wordpress gama website

Tags: wordpress

I am running on wordpress for the reference you can see https://www.coolmathgamestop.com/avie-pocket-birthday/ . I am using arcade plugin pro and fungames themes by same developer. I am very new to wordpress and in learning mode. The problem on my page is when myself or visitor try to play flash games they won't load and give empty box meanwhile on address bar a shield come with notice " this page is trying to load script from unauthenticated source" then there is option to allow loading script. coz of this error my visitor leave my page and never return . this error comes on half of my games. I have try and successfully install HTTPS:// but still this error comes. I have talk to developer of plugin and he said that issue is not on my end. [see image with errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YCS2.png)
Due to this error I lost a lot of visitors , even 0 traffic due to not loading a game.
I need help to get rid off this error .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because belongs on Wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

The issue is caused by assets (in your case, an SWF file) on the page being loaded insecurely over HTTP, even though the page itself is secured using HTTPS - This is known as a mixed-content issue.

Taking a look at the URL you provided, I can see that the problem seems to be the following:

```
swfobject.embedSWF( 'http://files.cdn.spilcloud.com/df9aa4793b5/APB-30-11/index.html', 'myarcade_swfobject_content', '807', '633', '9.0.0', '', [], {"wmode":"direct","allowscriptaccess":"always","swLiveConnect":"true","quality":"high"}, []);
```

Note that the path at the start of this is using `http://` instead of `https://`.

Try changing this to `https` if it is in the page content, otherwise if it is part of a plugin then contact the plugin developers/maintainers to see if they will provide a solution.

As I can see from the image you supplied, you're using Google Chrome, a useful tool is the "Network" tab of the Developer tools included with the browser. If you're not familiar with Chrome's DevTools, you can find out more here - https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Another good utility for diagnosing mixed-content issues are free online services, such as "[Why No Padlock](https://www.whynopadlock.com/)"

Comment: Thank you for quick response sir. I am new to wordpress so do not know alot about fixing . few days back my https:// was crossed line with red line also so i did install a plugin 'SSL Insecure Content Fixer ' which i was able to correct my https from red to green but this problem is still same. Can you guide me more to sort this out ? or shall i stop flashing games to upload and block it ?

Comment: one more thing sir .. I have enable an option which is called " Use SWFobjects , Activate this if you want to use SWFObject to embed Flash games." if I disable this can I solve my problem ?